# Do I need SSL Layer for my website if I use Paypal Standard Payment?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, paypal, ubercart

If I use the completely free service Paypal Standard Payment together with Drupal Ubercart module, do I need to enable SSL Secure Layer for my website ?

I guess I don't need it because the credit cards numbers are inserted in Paypal.

ps. Can I embed paypal into mywebsite instead of forwarding my customers ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. if you use Paypal standard you do not need an ssl certificate because the sensitive transaction data is only passed on Paypal's site.

There is a way to charge with paypal on your site but it is hard to setup costs more and would require an ssl certificate. If you are interested it is called Paypal Payflow

Comment: ok. One more thing: can I customize Paypal Standard pages.. adding my logo.. and possibly customize layout colors... or not ?

Comment: I haven't actually touched a paypal standard page for about 5 years so I am not sure how it works, but there should be some customization options for the page

Comment: @Sruly Paypal Standard can be customized.